# Zend Route is not loading the controllers

Tags: php, apache, routes, zend-framework2

I have this route settings:

```
return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'padrao' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/:controller[/:action][/:id]',
                'constrants' => array(
                    'id' => '[0-9]+'
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action' => 'index' 
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
    ),

),

'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'index' => 'Academia\Controller\IndexController',
        'usuarios' => 'Academia\Controller\UsuarioController'
    ),
),
```

The controllers are created and the views to,but the I put something like "http://server.com" or "http://server.com/index" or "http://server.com/usuarios/list", I get 404 errors in my browser.In the first case "http://server.com" I get the 404 in the zend page,in the others cases is the 404 error default from apache.There is something I forget?I saw some others similar questions from here StackOverflow where the index controller didn't work but in my case the two controllers don’t work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try the following
                   ` 'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'TheNamespaceName\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Index',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),`

Answer (score 0):

After some research I discovered the problem was the apache server,after enabling the apache rewrite module all the routes worked.